# QTableWidget - setCellWidget missing addition?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qtablewidget

I am just trying to add widgets into my table widget and I am trying the code below but all the time I run the program, the first widget is added but the rest is not added. Can you please help me for this situation ?

```
if(req.at(index).request.CodedValue.size() > 1 )
{
    int rowNumber = -1;
    for ( int paramNumber = 0 ; paramNumber < req.at(index).request.params.size(); paramNumber++)
    {

        if(req[index].request.params[paramNumber].semantic == "DATA")
        {
            rowNumber++;
            QComboBox* reqComboBox = new QComboBox();
            QLineEdit* tableReqLineEdit = new QLineEdit();

            for ( int codedCounter = 0; codedCounter < req.at(index).request.CodedValue.at(paramNumber).trams.size(); codedCounter++)
            {
                // you should look for the subfunctions and add according to them   
                reqComboBox->addItem((req[index].request.CodedValue[paramNumber].trams[codedCounter].valueName));
                QObject::connect(reqComboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(on_tableCombobox_currentIndex());
            }
            ui.tableWidget->setCellWidget(rowNumber,1,reqComboBox);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger to find out what's going on...

Comment: I have tried but everything seems OK, do we have to enable sth for increment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`qDebug`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdebug.html) in order to see how many times the for loop is executed. Probably it is executed only once:

```
#include <QDebug>
...
      rowNumber++;
      qDebug() << rowNumber;
...
```

Try the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<ui.tableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
{
      ui.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i,1,new QLineEdit);
}
```

How many line edits do you see?

Notice that you should use the `setRowCount` in order to set the number of rows of your table widget.

Comment: I really tried and I can see that it changes :( no problem with that